# Saving an Mutable Array into file via writeToFile

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray, writetofile

```
for(int x = 0; x < [tags count]; x++){
    NSString* tagsValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d: %f", 1, 
    [[tags objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];

    [[tagsValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath 
    atomically:NO];
}
```

i understand that writeToFile will replace the file itself so it would of give the final value of the array value.
How could i approach this i've been trying to get this around my head for a few hours but i've had no luck thanks! :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are trying to write a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to write directly array to file.

1. convert your array in string format.

   ```
   NSString *tagsCompleteStr = [tags componentJoinedByString:@" "];
   [tagsCompleteStr  writeToFile:fileAtPath 
                                          atomically:NO];
   ```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will add the **tagsValue** string at the end of the file,

 *Make sure you have already created the file.*

```
   for(int x = 0; x < [tags count]; x++){
       NSString* tagsValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d: %f", 1, [[tags objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];
       NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileAtPath];
       [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
       [myHandle writeData:[tagsValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   }
```

Comment: thanks heaps! that actually worked :D but how would i be able to use that file to pull information i can remake an array????

Comment: try this, NSArray *lines = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                          error:nil]
             componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];